# MS SQL column with fixed number of symbols

Tags: sql-server, sqldatatypes

I'm using MS SQL and creating a table.
One of the columns should contain a string with 4 symbols: `L001`, `L002`
There cannot be less or more symbols, e.g. `L01` and `L0001` are errors.

Which type of data I need to use? `CHAR(4)` and `NCHAR(4)` allow me to create `L01` and it's wrong in my case.

Comment: If the value can have non-ASCII characters, then `NCHAR(4)` otherwise `CHAR(4)`. For the formatting, you need a `CHECK` `CONSTRAINT`.

Comment: Is the format always meant to be 1 letter, followed by 3 digits?

Comment: No, it's not specified, so letter can also be it the middle of the string like `0L10`

Comment: Are the expected "symbols" always `0-9` or `A-Z`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should to use `CHECK CONSTRAINT`:
It possible to create table with constraint

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    ID int NOT NULL,
    Code varchar(4),
    CHECK (LEN(Code) = 4)
);
```

or update exist table:

```
CREATE TABLE Test (
    ID INT NOT NULL,
    Code CHAR(4)
);

ALTER TABLE Test 
   ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_Code_LEN   
   CHECK (LEN(Code) = 4);
```

Test:

```
INSERT INTO Test VALUES (1, 'L001'); -- data inserted

INSERT INTO Test VALUES (2, 'L0011'); -- error raised

INSERT INTO Test VALUES (2, 'L11'); -- error raised
```

Result:

```
SELECT * FROM Test;

+====+======+
| ID | Code |
+====+======+
| 1  | L001 |
+----+------+
```

[MS SQL fiddle CHECK](https://sqlize.online/sql/mssql2017/4506f5fae28ae957a618c681b23713b9/)

Comment: ' {3spaces}1' is allowed

Comment: The solution with `CHECK` worked fine for me, I didn't know about such solution, thank you!